# Corona SDK system.orientation returns wrong value on iphone?

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

I've noticed that system.orientation on launching an app give the default orientation as defined in build.settings for an iphone5S.  I've tested the same code on iPad2 and iPadMini and get the correct answer, but with iphone5S I always get the build.settings default setting regardless of which orientation the app launches in, any hints or ideas ?

build.settings

```
orientation = {
    default = "portrait",
supported = {
  "landscapeLeft", "landscapeRight", "portrait", "portraitUpsideDown"
}
```

main.lua

```
print ( system.orientation ) -- gives wrong answer on iphone5S but not ipad2 or ipad Mini ?
```

I'm using print as an example, I actually send the string to the device screen.

I basically have to rotate the 5S to start getting the correct orientation details, by default tit always says "portrait".  Which as you can imagine is annoying to say the least running my app on iphone5S.

Using build: Version 2013.2100 (2013.12.7)

Comment: have you tried using an orientation listener as explained at http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/orientation/index.html? At least you can rebuild your scene regardless of system.orientation.

Comment: yep, it's the initial orientation that getting the wrong result on iphone5S only with ios 7.05.  I can't build the scene properly has there is no event called as orientation has not changed. However system.orientation has invalid result that is not the current orientation.

Comment: ah yes, so could it be that the variable has not been initialized at the time when your code checks? See if you can delay checking it, maybe with a timer event, maybe it becomes set properly after a second or so.

Comment: Nah, too much of a hack and considering it works on other ios based devices it's looking like 7.05 or 5S issue to me.

Comment: I also believe it is an issue specific to that platform, the question is whether you want a workaround or not. The timer idea is a nice one IMO, hardly a hack: it will work on all platforms, and won't stop working as a result of an upgrade, and if you do it right it can easily be removed by commenting out one line of code, or could even be used only for that platform (assuming corona has a platform identification tag you can query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it.

iPad you can trust system.orientation ... but iPhone you must wait for the first "orientation" change to occur before you can trust it !! Assuming you have a deviceType in your code something like this works,

```
if (deviceType.isApple and not deviceType.is_iPad) then
    system.setAccelerometerInterval(100)   -- Make sure we capture first orientation change by ramping up the sample to 100Hz
    Runtime:addEventListener("orientation", initialOrientationSet) -- capture this first change
else
  -- Launch your app
end
```

Inside the initialOrientationSet do this:

```
function initialOrientationSet ()
  Runtime:removeEventListener("orientation", initialOrientationSet)
  system.setAccelerometerInterval (10) -- save some battery power
  -- Launch you app
end
```

Also you will have to test for simulator and launch that normally.

Cheers